# How to split a file in place without using buffers?

Tags: java, file

I am sure that we can create a `Buffer` and use `BufferedReader` to read the file using the `read(Buffer buffer)` method.

I have been trying to check if in place read is possible and want to understand what are the implications and complexities involved. Also, If this can be done in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NIO (New IO) will allow creating memory mapped files with MappedByteBuffer, see:

https://howtodoinjava.com/java-7/nio/java-nio-2-0-memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer-tutorial/